# Heading in jade within a table

Tags: html, pug

My example of my .jade file

```
h1 Head1
 table(border='1')
  tr
   td name
   td name2
  tr
   td data
   td data2
```

Now I want to put h2 @ td data. The result is, that the heading works, but the table is broken. The "data" is correctly with h2 but jumped out of the table. How is the right syntax?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jade doesn't seem to allow for multiple tags to be on the same line, which is probably your issue.

Based on the [online demo for Jade](http://jade-lang.com/demo/), seems like you want:

```
h1 Head1
 table(border='1')
  tr
   td name
   td name2
  tr
   td
    h2 data
   td data2
```

Although, if you do that, the entire table will be h1 formatted due to table being indented, which can be problematic, thus you probably actually want:

```
h1 Head1
table(border='1')
 tr
  td name
  td name2
 tr
  td 
   h2 data
  td data2
```

Which gives the following HTML:

```
<h1>Head1</h1>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>name</td>
    <td>name2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> 
      <h2>data</h2>
    </td>
    <td>data2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Note that the following two blocks of HTML give the same output:

```
<td> 
  <h2>data</h2>
</td>

<td><h2>data</h2></td>
```